# on click on label go to next page

Tags: swift

When I created a button earlier it had the ability to be an "action" IBA function..

How can I create the same thing with a label? so when I click the label my app will direct to a new page. (and how can I make it to direct to a new page? would I have to make a totally new view and in some way link it to that)

Please bare in mind, I'm a totally new to swift and have already come along way with my program,but its been pieces from several tutorials and therefor I might have a hard time understanding your answer the first time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` for that and below is simple example for you:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.userInteractionEnabled = true
        label.text = "I'am a test label"
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
        label.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("next")
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Project [sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=58082350993546630608) for more Info.

Comment: I get this when I try to run the code in my app: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) "

Comment: Show your full crash log

Comment: Do you mean everything from my "all output" ? (sorry, new to Xcode.)

Comment: Yes all output from console. And you can paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and share a link

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13007166/

As you can see Ive used your code with the label: nextLevel

Edit: It says it does not contain a view called "next".

Is this the problem? if so, how can I create a "next" view in Xcode?

Comment: I found out I had forgot to set my next view with the id "next". IT works now, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

1- Make sure you've checked the "User Interaction Enabled" in attributes inspector.

2- Code:

```
       let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourVC.labelTapped))
       yourLabel.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

3- Use the func:

```
    func labelTapped() {
    print("labelTapped tapped")
}
```